# Quartz persistent job scheduler implementation in java using oracle read only access

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

Here is scenario,

I am working on one web application,where I am using java, spring, oracle. My requirement is schedule some job where user should specify execution time by some UI and job should be persistent once schedule even if server restarted or application redeployed.
From last few days I am going through lots of stackoverflow post regarding  quartz persistence scheduler, but here is tricky part I can not execute any update or insert statement from my java code, I am only allowed to do all db stuff in plsql procedure and call that procedure from java code.

So, the problem is I can't go for quartz persistence implementation directly.It will very great full if anyone tell me right approach to deal with it.
in short how I can implement my own table structure and plsql procedure to make job persistence,which I can load once on application/server start and also allow user to update trigger time and other parameters.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking is for the Quartz JdbcJobStore which stores the jobs and track their execution. Please read the following:

- For configuring the JdbcJobStore read [this (TX)](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/configuration/ConfigJobStoreTX) or [this (CMT)](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/configuration/ConfigJobStoreCMT)
- For configuring the data sources [read this](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/configuration/ConfigDataSources)

Answer (score 0):

@Gan, If you want, you can customize quartz persistance by overriding  `JobStoreCMT` class of Quartz and using that as your job store class in quartz.properties as value for property `org.quartz.jobStore.class`.

```
#============================================================================
# Configure JobStore  
#============================================================================

 org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
 org.quartz.jobStore.class = <package>.CustomJobStoreCMT
```